# Angular reactive form - field custom validator

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to implement a custom field validator.
Validator code looks like this:

```
test(formGroup: FormGroup): ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  let error = { text: ''};
  console.log(formGroup);
  return error.text != '' ? error : null;
  };
}
```

I need to reference different form fields in that validator. I am having a problem accessing these fields. I am sending the form object into the validator, but it's undefined. Need some help here.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-builder-in-reactive-forms-2w3b9a?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Thanks

Comment: Try to set validator after your form is already initialized this.yourForm.get('yourFieldName').setValidators(test(this.yourForm))

Answer (score 0):

At the time the test function is called, myGroup is still being constructed and assigned. This is why formGroup is printing as undefined.

I think changing the code like this will helps you

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.myGroup = this.fb.group({
     firstName: 'Chethana',
     middleName: ['Dibbahalli', [this.test]],
     lastName: { value: 'DC', disabled: true }
 });
}

test(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  let error = { text: '' };
  return error.text !== '' ? error : null;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what would that work?

Comment: Your code does not look like mine and it's not working for me. Can you try in the attached example?

Answer (score 0):

You are capturing `formGroup` in `this.test(this.formGroup)` call before it's created. Of course it's undefined!

If you need access to all fields from FormGoup in validator, attach validator to FormGroup, not control.

There is a good article with examples in official documentation https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation